# Impala CONV function not consistently converting BASE-16 to BASE-2

Tags: hive, binary, hex, cloudera, impala

I have hex strings that I need to convert to Base-2 binary strings, but I cannot get Impala to perform consistently.

E.g.

I would expect this statement:

```
select conv('0020008000',16,2) union
select conv('000006040A',16,2);
```

To return:

```
0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0000 0100 0000 1010
```

However, instead it's returning:

```
0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000
                          1100 0000 1000 0001 010
```

The 1st HEX value is converted correctly, but the 2nd is missing the first 21 digits (all zeros).

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impala/Hive treats multiple leading zeros as redundant and trims them. I'm not sure if this behavior can be toggled on/off. I worked around it using lpad function.